# Share external function with datashare in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to share the external function that we have with original snowflake account to the datashare?

If not, is there any other way to use external function with datashare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only object types that can be included in a share are listed [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-intro) and that doesn’t include external functions.

Where are you sharing the objects to? As long as it is one of your accounts (and not a reader account) why not just re-create the external function in that account?